# Errors after importing Maven project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I imported a Maven project into Eclipse.  I was able to deploy it from the command line.  In Eclipse it is full of red Xs.  I have cleaned the project, updated the configuration and I ran the following command:

`mvn -Declipse.workspace=<pathtoworksapce> eclipse:add-maven-repo`

and I still have the same problem.  The project is dependent on another project.

Comment: I also faced the same issue.Try to import the project once again.May be it will solve the issue.

Comment: What problems are shown? "*Full of red Xs*" is not enough information to comment about what is wrong. Please can you edit your question to include some additional information.

Comment: Duncan, "red Xs" mean compilation errors (i.e. dependencies that are not imported correctly)

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu All we know is Eclipse is reporting errors after importing a project. In my opinion we need more information about the errors before a solution can be suggested.

Comment: @Duncan, these red Xs are dependency problems.  So the individual errors aren't really important. There was something wrong with the setup in Eclipse.  I did find the issue and have posted my solution.  Thanks

Comment: @user994165 It was important to know they were dependency problems!

Comment: @Duncan, understood.  When I said that the projects compiled fine from the command line using "mvn" I thought it was implied that the problem must be with the configuration in Eclipse but I should have been more explicit.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was removing all of the projects in Eclipse, but not deleting the source files.  Then instead of directly importing the code as Maven->Check out as Maven Projects with SCM, I selected Existing Maven Project and imported the code from my local machine.  This got rid of the errors, but when I would right click on code and select "Open Declaration", I would get Error: Could not open the editor:  The file does not exist"  So I removed all projects again and this time I deleted all the ".project" files and repeated the import Existing Maven Project.  So now there are no red Xs (dependency problems) and the lookup functionality within the code works.

Comment: @eis, I originally did a "Maven->checkout Maven Projects from SCM".  That imports and creates all the projects.  Somehow the generated Eclipse project configurations were not good.  I also had problems when I did an import using "SVN->Project from SVN".  When I imported into Eclipse using the already checked out files on my hard drive, it was fine.  That's after removing those .project files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your master project and type the following : 
         
**mvn install
         
mvn eclipse:eclipse**
After that, import your project. You can also install **m2eclipse** for better support. If you use gwt or any other framework which has a custom maven execution, you should also install plugins for those in Eclipse.

Comment: The install will build all your projects, and the eclipse:eclipse task will add your dependencies, so you don't have to import all your projects.

Comment: How can you be so sure this answers the question? Do you know the OP hasn't followed these steps already?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. You could instead try to answer the OP's question. Wouldn't this be a better approach?

Comment: Once the OP has posted sufficient information to deduce the cause of the problems, I will attempt to do so.

Comment: @Alex Calugarescu, I did issue those two commands but it didn't help.  Also, from what I had read, those commands only work if you have a single project. The one I listed in my question is supposed to work for multiple projects.  I did find the issue and have posted the solution.  Thanks

Comment: Those command work for a project hierarchy in maven. You should try installing all the project dependencies if the builds are not available on a maven server (i.e. issue the install command for them). Maybe some more reading about how maven works will help?